# How to access datas from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable

```
var chartData = [];
```

I have entered a few datas in that variable as inside a for loop :

```
for(i=0;i<31;i++)
var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
                        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);
                        i++;

                        chartData.push({
                            date: newDate,
                            visits: i 
                        });
```

The datas have entered in the array. but now i want to access those datas in a table again applying a for loop to make table rows. how to do that? I tried

```
document.write= " <tr> <td style='width:25%'>" + chartData.date[i] + " </td> <td style='width:25%'>" + chartData.visits[i] + "</td> <td style='width:25%'> " + chartData.visits[i]*i + " </td> <td style='width:25%'> " + chartData.visits[i]*chartData.visits[i] + " </td> </tr>";
```

But Couldnt get the datas... help needed. thankyou in advance..

Comment: You are increasing `i` twice in the loop. Was that indended?

Answer (score 4):

Close ... try ...

```
chartData[i].date 
chartData[i].visits
chartData[i].visits
chartData[i].visits*chartData[i].visits
```

The index is on `chartData`, not in the object inside; as you add objects to the array, the index increments against `chartData`.

Answer (score 1):

`chartData.date[i]` should actually be `chartData[i].date` because its the `chartData` variable that represents the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you use push, push function sets the index automatically from zero.
So your elements in tha array become like this:

```
chartData[0]={ date: newDate,visits: 0 }
chartData[1]={ date: newDate,visits: 1 }
```

so you can access elements from array:

```
 chartData[your_index].date 
 chartData[your_index].visits
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for accessing an Object value inside an array is

```
arrayname[index].Obj_Key
```

In your case, it should be

```
chartData[i].date
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cv29feuo/)** for better understanding based on your code.